# Read multiple files from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, httprequest

I receive a request (HttpServletRequest req) with 2+ files.
I am doing this in order to get files from request

```
HttpServletRequest req;

....

Map parameters = req.getParameterMap();

UploadedFile uploadedFile = (UploadedFile) parameters.get("file");

String[] serverNames = uploadedFile.getServerFileNames();
debug(serverNames.length);
```

However I always get only 1 file. What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: [Upload file using Servlet API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet). What is `UploadedFile`? Is it from JSF?

Comment: The parameter map has type `Map<String, String[]>`, it can not hold the uploaded file. If you are using Servlet API 3.0, you can use `getPart(String)` method. If you are using an older version, you need a library to parse the input stream.

Comment: @luke Lee you are right, but the way it works, files are already uploaded on server and I only receive their file names. UploadedFile class actually contains only file name on server.

Answer (score 0):

If your ***parameters*** contains a list of files, you can use :

```
for (Entry entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() instanceof UploadedFile) {
        UploadedFile file = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: in my case all files are in 1 place. I only have "File" parameter in request with multiple flies.

Comment: So you can cast your parameters like this : parameters = (Map) parameters.get("file"); and try the solution i suggest

Answer (score 0):

You use multipart form data and should correctly handle all parts or request.
Excample from [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet)

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
    //handling...
}
```